# Return used values from a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, .net-core

I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the values of the parameters and the variables used inside the function body of a lambda expression in C#.

For example:

```
decimal a = -0.5m;
decimal b = 2m;
Func<decimal,decimal> f = t => a*t + b; // Linear equation of t
Console.WriteLine(FunctionToString(f)); // Generate something like "-0.5 * t + 2"
```

I have tried redefining the lambda function inside of an Expression, like this:

```
decimal a = -0.5m;
decimal b = 2m;
Expression<Func<decimal,decimal>> xf = t => a*t + b; // Linear equation of t (Expression)
Console.WriteLine(xf); // Prints t => ((value(cTreatmentGraphing.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).a * t) + value(cTreatmentGraphing.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).b)
```

But this does not yield the values that would actually be used in the computation of the lambda expression, it just returns its structure.

Is it possible to work out the values at runtime and show the filled-in coefficients of a lambda expression, and if yes, how should I go about this?

Comment: When you have `Expression<Func<decimal,decimal>>` you can parse and extract the parameters and method body. Once you're calling `Compile()` you'll get back a `Func<decimal,decimal>` that you can simply invoke and get your desired return value

Comment: Hi @haim770, thanks for your comment, but I am looking to print the expression that's being used to calculate the lambda, not the function output of the lambda itself. For the example above, I would like to generate a string somehow that is something in the likes of "-0.5 * t + 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you use expression trees, and write a visitor that rewrites the tree, resolving captured variables; essentially, captured variables are implemented as a tree of member-lookups which resolve eventually to a `ConstantExpression` that is the capture-context; note that you need to do this recursively, because capture-contexts can be nested if different variables are captured at different scopes. Once you have the member-infos and target object (capture-context) for each level, you can use reflection to *evaluate* the captured variable:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

class Dong
{
    public static implicit operator Dong(int i) => throw new InvalidOperationException("int");

    public static implicit operator Dong(decimal d) => throw new InvalidOperationException("decimal");

    static void Main()
    {
        decimal a = -0.5m;
        decimal b = 2m;
        Expression<Func<decimal, decimal>> f = t => a * t + b; // Linear equation of t
        Console.WriteLine(FunctionToString(f)); // Generate something like "-0.5 * t + 2"
    }

    static string FunctionToString(Expression f)
        => ConstantEvaluator.Instance.Visit(f).ToString();
    class ConstantEvaluator : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public static ConstantEvaluator Instance { get; } = new ConstantEvaluator();
        private ConstantEvaluator() { }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var target = Visit(node.Expression); // applies recursion of nested contexts
            if (target is ConstantExpression c)
            {
                switch (node.Member)
                {
                    case FieldInfo field:
                        return Expression.Constant(field.GetValue(c.Value), field.FieldType);
                    case PropertyInfo prop:
                        return Expression.Constant(prop.GetValue(c.Value), prop.PropertyType);
                }
            }
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
t => ((-0.5 * t) + 2)
```

Note that you can also use:

```cs
static string FunctionToString(LambdaExpression f)
    => ConstantEvaluator.Instance.Visit(f.Body).ToString();
```

if you don't want the lambda declaration; this gives output:

```
((-0.5 * t) + 2)
```

Comment: Awesome, I had never used reflection before but I guess this is a prime example of where it shines. I believe this answers my question!

Comment: @JansthcirlU note that I tweaked the "visit" code a tiny bit, so we only override `VisitMember`, not `Visit`